# TypeScript Error: (TS1128) Declaration or statement expected

Tags: reactjs, typescript, build-error

I have a TypeScript Error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected. I've spent couples of hours and I can't find the mistake... It is in master/node_modules/@theme-ui/core/dist/index.d.ts (4, 1):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './react-jsx';
export type { CSSObject, CSSOthersObject, CSSProperties, CSSPseudoSelectorProps, ColorMode, ColorModesScale, Label, ResponsiveStyleValue, Scale, StylePropertyValue, TLengthStyledSystem, Theme, ThemeDerivedStyles, ThemeStyles, ThemeUICSSObject, ThemeUICSSProperties, ThemeUIExtendedCSSProperties, ThemeUIStyleObject, VariantProperty, } from '@theme-ui/css';
export * from './types';
export declare const jsx: typeof React.createElement;
export interface ContextValue {
    __EMOTION_VERSION__: string;
    theme: Theme;
}
export declare const Context: React.Context<ContextValue>;
export declare const useThemeUI: () => ContextValue;
/**
 * Deeply merge themes
 */
export declare const merge: {
    (a: Theme, b: Theme): Theme;
    all: typeof mergeAll;
}
declare function mergeAll<A, B>(a: A, B: B): A & B;
declare function mergeAll<A, B, C>(a: A, B: B, c: C): A & B & C;
declare function mergeAll<A, B, C, D>(a: A, B: B, c: C, d: D): A & B & C & D;
interface BaseProviderProps {
    context: ContextValue;
}
export interface ThemeProviderProps {
    theme: Theme | ((outerTheme: Theme) => Theme);
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}
export declare function ThemeProvider({ theme, children }: ThemeProviderProps): React.FunctionComponentElement<BaseProviderProps>;
```

Comment: You should probably tell typescript to ignore your node_modules folder entirely. No reason to check against things you can't fix. If it's happening in a particular external dependency, you can submit an issue (or pull request to fix it) in the git repo where the project is hosted. Check the `node_modules/theme-ui/package.json` file to find that.

Answer (score 2):

Try that below:

```
 npm uninstall -g typescript
 npm install typescript --save-dev
```

Comment: you don't need to uninstall typescript globally just 

`npm uninstall typescript` works.

my typescript was in dependencies instead of devdependencies